# NuGet package solution with multiple projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dependency-injection, nuget-package, class-library

I have a solution with 3 class library projects in it. I'm using dependency injection to create loose coupling among these projects which are:

- Services which are actual functions
- Domain
- Repository

So, ultimately, my NuGet package would only be exposing the functions in "Services" but service functions use repository methods and domain objects. So all should be included in my package.

Here's where I'm confused:

1. How do I make sure my NuGet package will include all the necessary pieces in it i.e. domain objects and repository methods. Domain objects are exposed but repository methods are only consumed by service functions so ultimately they're not visible to users. Nevertheless, my service functions need them so they must be included in the package.
2. I'm also confused about tying the 3 projects together which is typically done at the top level. In other words, installing the NuGet package would not be enough as the dependencies need to be resolved. For example, if I add my NuGet package in a new ASP.NET project, I'd have to resolve these dependencies in my Startup.cs which seems a bit awkward. Not sure how to handle that part.
3. Each project has its own dependencies. For example, Repository project uses Azure Table Storage and the services project uses NewtonSoft.Json. I want to make sure ALL dependencies will be covered when the user installs my NuGet package in a new project.

How do I go about creating this NuGet package?